# If a graph is k-partite then its chromatic number is less or equal to k

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring

I read this sentence in my notes. I searched it, and it seems to be a theorem . I can see how if a graph is k-partite we can colour it in k - colours( as k - partite means that the graph can be divided into k - independent sets).
If a graph is k-partite , in which  cases the chromatic number is (strictly) less than k ? I assume that , there is such a chance if this k - partition is not a minimum one ( for examample we can actually partite the graph into less than k independent sets) . But if by k-partite we mean that we can partite our graph in no less than k independent sets then the chromatic number shouldn't be exactly k? (help me brainstorm)

Comment: The typical definition of $k$-partite graph never says that it cannot be $k'$-partite for some $k'<k$ (or, as you say, there is no requirement that you have the best partition; if there were, it would just be another name for having chromatic number $k$).

Comment: okay , but what are the cases that the chromatic number is less than  k?

Comment: For example every graph with $n$ vertices is $n$-partite.

Comment: no I mean .. can we be a little bit more specific on  cases  in which the chromatic number of a k- partite graph is less that k ?

Comment: OK. The graph consisting of 2 vertices and no edges is 2-partite, and its chromatic number is 1.